# TSQL inserting data into table after getting from select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a select statement that is looking up records based on an XML string of employee ID's that I am sending to it.

It checks certain criteria as well as checking if the data exists in another table.

Once it returns the data, I need to then ADD that data into the table it wasn't found in.

I am just not sure how this would work as I think this block of code runs each time before getting to the next section which would be the insert line.

How could I insert each of the `A.[employee]` into another table that it returns?

```
SELECT   A.[employee],
                 Sup.SupEmpID,
                 Sup.Email,
                 Sup.FirstName,
                 Sup.LastName,
                 sum(A.[awardValue]) AS totalAwarded
        FROM     taxTracker AS A
                 INNER JOIN
                 EmpTable AS E
                 ON A.employee = E.EmpID
                 INNER JOIN
                 EmpTable AS Sup
                 ON E.SupEmpID = Sup.EmpID
        WHERE    YEAR(A.[awardDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
                 AND employee IN (SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
                                  FROM   @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x1))
                 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT employee
                                 FROM   taxTrackerTracked
                                 WHERE  [year] = YEAR(GETDATE())
                                        AND employee IN (SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
                                                         FROM   @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x1)))
        GROUP BY employee, Sup.SupEmpID, Sup.Email, Sup.Firstname, Sup.LastName
        HAVING   SUM(A.[awardValue]) > '75.00'
        FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');

--An insert statement here
```

Comment: Do you need to return the resultset from the above query back to the client, or just insert values into a table without returning any result set?

Comment: Is the insert statement supposed to insert into `taxTrackerTracked` or some other table?

Comment: Correct, into the Tracked table. Example: Get data where its not in that table, now add it to that table but I also have the data in the XML output to work with from the original select

Comment: I need to do both - I need the data returned to my client side as well as inserting each of the records it finds into the other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really an XQuery expert but couldn't you just capture the output of your query into an XML variable and then `SELECT` the variable to return it to the client, and then use XQuery again (you're already using it in your query) to extract the value you need and use this with an `INSERT` statement.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML = (
    SELECT
        A.[employee],
        Sup.SupEmpID, Sup.Email, Sup.FirstName, Sup.LastName,
        sum(A.[awardValue]) AS [totalAwarded]
    FROM taxTracker AS A
    INNER JOIN EmpTable AS E
        ON A.employee = E.EmpID
    INNER JOIN EmpTable AS Sup
        ON E.SupEmpID = Sup.EmpID
    WHERE YEAR(A.[awardDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND employee IN (
        SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
        FROM @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x1)
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT employee
        FROM   taxTrackerTracked
        WHERE  [year] = YEAR(GETDATE())
        AND employee IN (
            SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
            FROM @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x1)
        )
    )
    GROUP BY employee, Sup.SupEmpID, Sup.Email, Sup.Firstname, Sup.LastName
    HAVING SUM(A.[awardValue]) > '75.00'
    FOR XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
)

SELECT @x

INSERT taxTrackerTracked ([employee])
SELECT r.d.query('data(employee)').value('/', 'INT') AS [employee]
FROM @x.nodes('/root/data') r (d)
```

Comment: This seemed to work just fine - just had to change the value type from int to varchar (our id's contain both)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the INSERT statement before the SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable (employee, SupEmpID, Email, FirstName, LastName, totalAwarded)
    SELECT   A.[employee],
                     Sup.SupEmpID,
                     Sup.Email,
                     Sup.FirstName,
                     Sup.LastName,
                     sum(A.[awardValue]) AS totalAwarded
            FROM     taxTracker AS A
                     INNER JOIN
                     EmpTable AS E
                     ON A.employee = E.EmpID
                     INNER JOIN
                     EmpTable AS Sup
                     ON E.SupEmpID = Sup.EmpID
            WHERE    YEAR(A.[awardDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
                     AND employee IN (SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
                                      FROM   @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x1))
                     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT employee
                                     FROM   taxTrackerTracked
                                     WHERE  [year] = YEAR(GETDATE())
                                            AND employee IN (SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
                                                             FROM   @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x1)))
            GROUP BY employee, Sup.SupEmpID, Sup.Email, Sup.Firstname, Sup.LastName
            HAVING   SUM(A.[awardValue]) > '75.00'
            FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

fix the Table name & column names in the insert statement to your actual names.

Comment: .. And the data will still be output to the XML that I need? Seems to easy haha - Thanks!

Comment: The issue with this is I dont need all of the data in my select statement; just the employee ; Not sure if its going to work that way